# BlobNotFound error - redirect to default file

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We use azure blob for storing website images uploaded by users and link them directly on our website.

E.g. a user uploads myPhoto.jpg file and we store it to maskedsubdomain.ourwebsite.com/Upload/ myPhoto.jpg, on the main website we use the same URL to show the image

```
<img src="https://maskedsubdomain.ourwebsite.com/Upload/myPhoto.jpg/>
```

Sometimes the image gets deleted or simply do not exist anymore (I'm of course simplifying the UC there are valid reasons for non-having the image anymore)

When we reference the image which doesn't exit Azure Blob returns

```
<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:8cdd3769-701e-00a0-0253-cca4f3000000 Time:2020-01-16T10:00:23.2322143Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

Is it possible instead of this message to have a custom one, ideally which returns the default image, something like user-friendly 404

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to the problem is to configure a storage account for static website hosting and then store the images in `$web` blob container (it's the blob container to serve static website content). As part of the configuration, you'll have the ability to specify custom pages for 404 (not found) error.

You can learn more about static website hosting in Azure Storage here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal.